# Multiple columns in single row in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have about 80k lines of flat data with fields as shown.

I am trying to create a pivot table that splits on Client, Department, Shift, Employee ID, first and last name, hours, weekending date.

I'd like the id#, last and first name, hour info and weekend date to all be on the same line.

Is that possible?

[image: Excel flat data and pivot table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design->Report Layout->Show in Tabular Form